# SSL/TLS passthrough in NGINX with querystring param

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to use an nginx reverse proxy with passthrough adding querystring parameter (apikey).
I would authenticate all requests that pass through this proxy.
I don't want use the apikey in original request.

This code works without adding querystring parameter:

```
stream {

  upstream example_upstream {
    
    server example.com:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;

  }


  server {
      listen     443;
      proxy_pass example_upstream;

  }

}
```

I have tried to add *rewrite* directive at row before proxy_pass as follow:

```
rewrite ^ http://example.com$uri?apikey=1 permanent;

or

rewrite ^ http://example.com$uri?apikey=1 permanent;
```

but I obtain this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "rewrite" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:row
```

what I can do it?

Comment: You can't do it with SSL/TLS passthrough, since it will require (encrypted) request modification, which is impossible without decrypting and re-encrypting the request.

Comment: is not only the payload encrypted when using SSL/TLS?

Comment: Everything including request string (e.g. `GET /api/endpoint?apikey=1 HTTP/1.1`), request headers (e.g. `Host: example.com`) and request body (which is what `GET` requests does not have, unlike `POST` or some other requests) **is** a payload. The only request information available to the server before the TLS handshake occurs is the accessed server hostname, passed via SNI Client Hello extension (see RFC 3546).